# Unit tests no longer runnable after upgrading from netcoreapp3.1 to net6.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a solution containing 2 projects, 1st is an asp application built on netcoreapp3.1, 2nd is the unit tests for that which are also built on netcoreapp3.1

I've updated the projects to use net6.0 and done a clean rebuild of the project.  This runs with no errors and reports the build succeeded.

After the upgrade, if I right click on the unit test project 'Run Tests' is greyed out (whereas it wasn't before the upgrade).  If I go to the Test Explorer and try to run the tests there, it hangs for a while before reporting that no tests were run.

The only output I get is as follows, but I can't work out why the upgrade would be creating this issue:

```
Aborting test discovery because a test run was requested.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to negotiate protocol, waiting for response timed out after 90 seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TestRequestSender.CheckVersionWithTestHost()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 1.5 min ==========
Building Test Projects
Starting test discovery for requested test run
========== Starting test discovery ==========
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to negotiate protocol, waiting for response timed out after 90 seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TestRequestSender.CheckVersionWithTestHost()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
Executing all tests in project: Products.Dashboard.UnitTests
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 1.5 min ==========
========== Starting test run ==========
========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
Resuming previously aborted test discovery
========== Starting test discovery ==========
```

Edit: this is the project file for the unit tests

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>{af563d15-3097-4430-89e5-6e80e6152dfa}</ProjectGuid>
    
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" Version="16.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\MainProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please show the unit test project file. You're probably missing the test adapter.

Comment: Have you tried "the usual" - manually removing bin and obj folders and/or restarting the VS (or sometimes even machine)? Also do not forget to upgrade packages (including unit testing ones).

Comment: @PMF Updated to include project file.  I've also tried manually deleting the bin/obj of all projects, and a full machine restart

Answer (score 1):

Getting the settings for an unit test project right is always a bit tricky, but I think you need to do the following. Remove the lines

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

.NET 6.0+ libraries and unit test assemblies should never use a platform target setting. It just kills flexibility without adding any value.

Add these dependencies:

```
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.utility" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
```

That should fix the test runner in Visual Studio (Restarting of VS might be necessary after this change)

Honestly, I'm not sure this fixes your errors, but that's the way it works for me. Note that if a test project is correctly recognized, it gets a different icon than other projects (one with a flask on it).

Comment: After this change I get 'Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.CodeCoverage from 17.5.0 to 16.10.0.  I've tried explicitly referencing that package but I can't seem to solve the issue

Comment: @Andy That error means that the new dependencies require a newer version of Microsoft.CodeCoverage. Upgrade the reference to Microsoft.CodeCoverage to V 17.5.0, as indicated in the error message. That should fix the issue.